# Object dot-notation is not working in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Object dot-notation does not work here as value is undefined

```
<Input key={i} value={inputs.e} name={e} onNameChange={handleChange} />
```

this works

```
<Input key={i} value={inputs[e]} name={e} onNameChange={handleChange} />
```

this is signifying to me that initializing state like this may not be the best idea?

```
function _Login() {
  const inputNames = ["firstName", "lastName"];
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState(
    inputNames
      .map((e) => ({ [e]: "" }))
      .reduce((accumulator, current) => ({ ...accumulator, ...current }), {})
  );
  const handleChange = (value: object) => setInputs({ ...inputs, ...value });

  return (
    <form>
      {inputNames.map((e, i) => (
        <Input key={i} value={inputs[e]} name={e} onNameChange={handleChange} />
      ))}
    </form>
  );
}
```

the reduce is just reducing an array of objects to one object

What is a good explanation for all of this?

Comment: Edit your question and convert your code sample into an interactive snippet. [How?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)

Comment: You are correct @JanezKuhar, thank you! It was a duplicate as I was trying to use dot notation to access a property name that is stored in a variable, which needs bracket notation.

Comment: Ah, then thank @PatrickRoberts and others ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66959080/revisions)). ^^

Comment: @JanezKuhar thank you for helping me with the revision history, and yes I will thank him!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you for your help as it is duplicate!